# Display issue with fresh install of windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server, windows-server-2012

I installed windows server 2012 last night on my home "server". I use server loosely. From the get go I had display and graphic issues. The image was fuzzy and jumbled up during the install. This continued once booted into the install.

I did installed Server 2012 twice now as the first time, I only installed "core". I know this is not a busted graphics card because it worked fine in Win7, during boot, and fine in "core" mode. Once booted into "GUI" install of Server 2012, the image was messed up again.

To make things even more weird, the windows "loading" screen looks fine. Once the login screen appears the image is fuzzy and jumbled.

My guess was that it was a driver issue. I did try to install the win8 x64 drivers from nvidia. This caused the system to become unbootable and I had to restore to a previous working point and uninstall the driver.

I did try two different monitors and cables. Also both ports on the back of the video card.

I did manage to get RDP running and that works fine. I rarely work directly on this machine but it would be nice to have the option back.

Geforce 210, 
AMD 4600+, 
4 gigs of ram.

Comment: Driver or video card issue.  Sounds like your video card doesn't support Server 2012, at least not yet.  Not much you can do about it.

Comment: @HopelessN00b if it was a new video card I could see that. But it has support for win8. Win8 and Server2012 is the same "core" under the covers. ./shrug Probably right none the less.